# How to create two pages from a same module?

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, layout-update

I created a module for displaying customized form for my website and its works  fine.

I want to duplicate the same page with extra one or two fields.

Is it possible to create another page from the same module?

If Yes how can i change the front name and phtml files(Different form with different front name)?

Current link for the page is www.domain.com/**subscribe**,

I want to create another link like www.domain.com/**subscribe_new**

**My config file**

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <htdgetresponse>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>HTD_Getresponse</module>
                <frontName>subscribe</frontName>
            </args>
        </htdgetresponse>
    </routers>
    <layout>
    <updates>
      <htdgetresponse>
        <file>htdgetresponse.xml</file>
      </htdgetresponse>
    </updates>
  </layout>
</frontend>
```

**My Layout.xml File**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<htdgetresponse_index_index>
<reference name="root">   
  <action method="setTemplate"><template>htdgetresponse/getresponse_manage.phtml</template></action>   
</reference>   
<reference name="content">   
  <block type="htdgetresponse/unsubscribe" name="unsubscribe" template="htdgetresponse/index.phtml"/>   
</reference>
</htdgetresponse_index_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add a second route. As you can see in your config file you already defined one in the  tags. Simply add a second one and copy paste your original phtml file, add your modifications and point your new route towards it. Please check out the section "Configuring Routes" [in the official Magento documentation here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-3.html).

Comment: thank you, i did the same yesterday and its success.i too update the answer, with what i did.

Answer (score 1):

Can Add the second router inside the **routers** tag.
I edit my file like below.

**My config file**

```
<frontend>
<routers>
    <htdgetresponse>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
            <module>HTD_Getresponse</module>
            <frontName>subscribe</frontName>
        </args>
    </htdgetresponse>

    <!-- newly added code-->
    <htdgetresponse_new>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
            <module>HTD_Getresponse</module>
            <frontName>subscribe_new</frontName>
        </args>
    </htdgetresponse_new>
    <!--------------->

</routers>
<layout>
<updates>
  <htdgetresponse>
    <file>htdgetresponse.xml</file>
  </htdgetresponse>

  <!-- newly added code-->
  <htdgetresponse_new>
    <file>htdgetresponse.xml</file>
  </htdgetresponse_new>
  <!--------------->

</updates>
```

**My Layout.xml File**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<htdgetresponse_index_index>
<reference name="root"> 
<action method="setTemplate"><template>htdgetresponse/getresponse_manage.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
<block type="htdgetresponse/unsubscribe" name="unsubscribe" template="htdgetresponse/index.phtml"/>
</reference>
</htdgetresponse_index_index>

<!-- newly added code-->
<htdgetresponse_new_index_index>   
<reference name="root">   
  <action method="setTemplate"><template>htdgetresponse/getresponse_manage_new.phtml</template></action>   
</reference>
</htdgetresponse_new_index_index>
<!--------------->

</layout>
```

And create new file called **getresponse_manage_new.phtml** in the template folder. That's it.